# How can i convert a textarea into a form?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, textarea, google-chrome-storage

Hi i need help converting a textarea into a basic form with three inputs for example... user can enter their first name, last name and email into a form. currently my code has a textarea which is being stored into chrome storage. Please help me convert this into a form and still have it stored and retrieved in chrome storage. Many thanks.

html:

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="saveLine"></textarea>
    <input type="button" id="save" value="Save Line">

    <input type="button" id="get" value="Get Saved Line">
```

JS File:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('save').onclick = function() {
    var value = document.getElementById('saveLine').value;

    chrome.storage.sync.set({'myLine': value}, function() {
        alert('success');
    });
};

document.getElementById('get').onclick = function() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get('myLine', function(data) {
        alert(data.myLine);
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Why the textarea element instead of separate first name, last name and email input elements?

Comment: What is your actual question? You have stated  what you "need", but have not actually asked a question, or explained where your *specific* problem is. You might want to read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237)

Comment: @Traktor53 this was originally a draft code i have modified, but i am struggling to modify it into a form.

Comment: You may not have heard of [the X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but the question reads like one. For example, a form is for submitting data to a server, and you have not indicated this is what you want to do...

Comment: @Traktor53 many apologises im still trying to figure this thing out as im very new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply wrap the HTML inputs/buttons/etc in a `form` element with an `action` attribute (though this is optional). You'll also want to change at least one button to be `type="submit"` in this case.

```
<form id="some_form" action="/some/endpoint">
  <textarea id="saveLine"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" id="save" value="Save Line">
  <input type="button" id="get" value="Get Saved Line">
</form>
```

You'll probably also want to handle form submission via your JS because if you want it to *also* submit to Chrome Storage, then you'll need to hijack the form `submit` handler.

```
var form = document.getElementById('some_form')
form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
  console.log('Form elements', form.elements)
  event.preventDefault()
  // Do your Chrome Storage stuff here with form elements
})
```